# webservice(xampp) doesn't work on mobile browser

Tags: android, xampp

i trying to connect (http connection) to xampp database but i got the up error
and the device that i running the app on has same laptop wifi, i try to add :80 after ip but nothing change 
and the url actually work [url work well in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8mO0.png)

and my logcat is

```
    E/dfdgfffffffffffff: http://127.0.0.1/Lotus/getscats.php?category=Atm
E/FSDGH: http://127.0.0.1/Lotus/getscats.php?category=Atm
V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0 ,Parent =ViewRoot{425e8978 com.example.karem.lotus/com.example.karem.lotus.Category_Activity,ident = 2}, this =com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{425c8048 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
D/ActivityThread: ACT-LAUNCH_ACTIVITY handled : 0 / ActivityRecord{425c5790 token=android.os.BinderProxy@425c4ef8 {com.example.karem.lotus/com.example.karem.lotus.Category_Activity}}
D/GraphicBuffer: create handle(0x641daf68) (w:720, h:1184, f:1)
I/MaliEGL: [Mali]window_type=1, is_framebuffer=0, errnum = 0
I/MaliEGL: [Mali]surface->num_buffers=4, surface->num_frames=3, win_min_undequeued=1
           [Mali]max_allowed_dequeued_buffers=3
D/GraphicBuffer: close handle(0x641daf68) (w:720 h:1184 f:1)
D/GraphicBuffer: create handle(0x641daf68) (w:720, h:1184, f:1)
D/OpenGLRenderer: setViewport 720x1184 <0x63bceca8>
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
V/InputMethodManager: onWindowFocus: android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView{425da188 VFED.... .F....ID 0,0-720,1022 #7f070023 app:id/category_recycler_view} softInputMode=272 first=true flags=#1810100
                      START INPUT: android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView{425da188 VFED.... .F....ID 0,0-720,1022 #7f070023 app:id/category_recycler_view} ic=null tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@43342cc8 controlFlags=#105
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 720.00, 1184.00) opaque 1 <0x63bceca8>
                  finish <0x63bceca8>
D/OpenGLRenderer: Flushing caches (mode 0)
D/GraphicBuffer: close handle(0x615712e0) (w:720 h:1184 f:1)
D/GraphicBuffer: close handle(0x62ff56b8) (w:720 h:1184 f:1)
D/GraphicBuffer: close handle(0x61583ee8) (w:720 h:1184 f:1)
                 close handle(0x6159f118) (w:720 h:1184 f:1)
I/System.out: No proyx setting for 127.0.0.1
D/dalvikvm: create interp thread : stack size=128KB
            create new thread
            new thread created
            update thread list
D/dalvikvm: threadid=13: interp stack at 0x617a7000
            threadid=13: created from interp
D/dalvikvm: start new thread
I/System.out: [socket][0] connection /127.0.0.1:80;LocalPort=52806(15000)
              [CDS]connect[/127.0.0.1:80] tm:15
D/Posix: [Posix_connect Debug]Process com.example.karem.lotus :80 
I/System.out: [socket][1:52806] exception
              [CDS]close[52806]
D/dalvikvm: threadid=13: notify debugger
            threadid=13 (OkHttp ConnectionPool): calling run()
E/fghjgjgf: Problem retrieving the earthquake JSON results.
            java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /127.0.0.1 (port 80) after 15000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
                at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:249)
                at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:178)
                at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
                at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
                at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:475)
                at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:861)
                at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:152)
                at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:101)
                at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:294)
                at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
                at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
                at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
                at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89)
                at com.example.karem.lotus.CategoryAsyncTaskUtils.makeHttpRequest(CategoryAsyncTaskUtils.java:58)
                at com.example.karem.lotus.CategoryAsycTask.doInBackground(CategoryAsycTask.java:20)
                at com.example.karem.lotus.CategoryAsycTask.doInBackground(CategoryAsycTask.java:11)
                at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
             Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
                at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:234)
                at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:178) 
                at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112) 
                at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192) 
                at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:475) 
                at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:861) 
                at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:152) 
                at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:101) 
                at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:294) 
                at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255) 
                at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206) 
                at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345) 
                at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89) 
                at com.example.karem.lotus.CategoryAsyncTaskUtils.makeHttpRequest(CategoryAsyncTaskUtils.java:58) 
                at com.example.karem.lotus.CategoryAsycTask.doInBackground(CategoryAsycTask.java:20) 
                at com.example.karem.lotus.CategoryAsycTask.doInBackground(CategoryAsycTask.java:11) 
                at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288) 
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
                at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841) 
I/System.out: close [socket][/0.0.0.0:52806]
V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4 ,Parent =ViewRoot{42300778 

com.example.karem.lotus/com.example.karem.lotus.MainActivity,ident = 1}, this =com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{422c8568 I.E..... R....... 0,0-720,1184}
    D/ActivityThread: ACT-STOP_ACTIVITY_HIDE handled : 0 / android.os.BinderProxy@422c5970
    D/dalvikvm: threadid=13: exiting
                threadid=13: bye!
```

and my http connection code is

```
public static String makeHttpRequest(URL url) throws IOException {
        String jsonResponse = "";
        Log.e("FSDGH", url.toString());

        // If the URL is null, then return early.
        if (url == null) {
            return jsonResponse;
        }

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            // If the request was successful (response code 200),
            // then read the input stream and parse the response.
            if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                jsonResponse = readFromStream(inputStream);
            } else {
                Log.e("vcvjgffghjj", "Error response code: " + urlConnection.getResponseCode());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("fghjgjgf", "Problem retrieving the earthquake JSON results.", e);
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close();
            }
        }
        return jsonResponse;

    }
```

i search on this problem but can't find answer that work for me

Comment: does it works well even on a browser on the phone ? i guess there's no open port from outside your laptop itself

Comment: no it didn't work from the phone browser @AlbertoCappellina

Comment: @AlbertoCappellina how to open port from ubuntu

Comment: can't help. look for some documentation